# Husemoller's definition of $\Phi$-topology and $\Phi$-defined: Having trouble understanding it

Tags: general-topology

I have trouble interpreting Husemoller's definition of $\Phi$-topology and $\Phi$-defined:

(i)

"Let $X$ be a set, and let $\Phi$ be a family of spaces $M$ whose
underlying sets are subsets of $X$. The $\Phi$-topology on $X$ is defined by requiring
a set $U$ in $X$ to be open if and only if  $U \cap M$ is open in $M$ for each $M \in \Phi$."

---

(ii)

"If
$X$ is a space and if $\Phi$ is a family of subspaces of $X$, the topology on $X$ is said
to be $\Phi$-defined provided the $\Phi$-topology on the set $X$ is the given topology
on $X$."

To help understand what he wrote, I attempted to rewrite things in a more structured and concise form. I would like a check on my rewrite.

---

(Notation)

Denote a topological space by $x \prec X$, where $x$ is an underlying set that $X$ is the topology on. We will never abuse notation: $X$ refers explicitly to the topology, but never to the underlying set (and vice versa). The infix $\ge$ denotes that the (topological) space on the right is a subspace of the other. The vertical $ \mid $ denotes "such that" or "where" (similar to how it is used in set builder notation.

---

---

My rewrite:

(i)

Let $S$ be a set with $s, t \subseteq S$. Let $\mathfrak{Eul}$ be a family of (topological) spaces $s \prec \mathfrak E$. Have a topological space
\begin{align}
S \prec T \;  \bigg | \; t  \in T \iff t \cap s \in \mathfrak E
\end{align}

We call $T$ the $\mathfrak{Eul}$ topology.

---

(ii)

Likewise, $T$ is said to be $\mathfrak{Eul}$-defined if we have

\begin{align}
\big( S \prec T \big) \ge \big( s \prec \mathfrak E \big)    \; \bigg| \; t \in T \iff  t \cap s \in \mathfrak E
\end{align}

Is this the correct interpretation of Husemoller's statement? Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151376/discussion-on-question-by-nate-husemollers-definition-of-phi-topology-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: This is a question about general topology. No other tags are adequate here.